# .NET Outlook addin: localised Ressource not loading on an end-user box

Tags: .net, internationalization

I've got an Outlook addin with a french default locale, and an EN localisation.

On addin startup, I make a call to

```
Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

Where Resourcesis an auto generated class:

```
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
```

On a dev box, it works well, english strings show up.

However, on an end user box, it's not the case.

I've got an 'en' subdirectory in my install folder containing my .resources.dll file.

My install may be lacking another file, but I don't know which.

Any idea on how to debug this kind of issue?

**Update:** process explorer tells me my ressource dll is loaded! It's slowly driving me nuts.

Basically, I've got a default locale (fr), and a satellite one (en). It might not be the good pattern...

**Update2:** No luck with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");` neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that satellite assemblies have to be in the GAC so as to be loaded by Outlook 2003.

Once it's done, it works.